# .pkpass giving file not supported on Apple device

Tags: c#, .net, wallet

I am currently working on apple wallet functionality where I have to save Event tickets in the user's apple wallet.

I am using NuGet package written by Tomas (https://github.com/tomasmcguinness/dotnet-passbook).

I am currently facing an issue like I have created a .pkpass file from the code and when I am trying to open that file in Apple device I am getting a **"File not supported issue"** but If I open the same pass in android (PassWallet or Passes) it works fine.

Anyone can help me here?

Below is my pass.json file

```html
{
  "passTypeIdentifier": "pass.tomsamcguinness.events",
  "formatVersion": 1,
  "serialNumber": "121212",
  "description": "My first pass",
  "organizationName": "Test Org",
  "teamIdentifier": "4T64559QVN",
  "sharingProhibited": false,
  "logoText": "Test Inc.",
  "foregroundColor": "rgb(0,0,0)",
  "labelColor": "rgb(0,0,0)",
  "barcodes": [
    {
      "format": "PKBarcodeFormatCode128",
      "message": "10000151",
      "messageEncoding": "ISO-8859-1",
      "altText": "10000010"
    }
  ],
  "eventTicket": {
    "headerFields": [
      {
        "key": "date",
        "label": "Date",
        "value": "16th July"
      }
    ],
    "primaryFields": [
      {
        "key": "event-name",
        "label": "Event",
        "value": "The Hectic Glow in concert"
      }
    ],
    "secondaryFields": [
      {
        "key": "location",
        "label": "Location",
        "value": "Central Park Zoo"
      }
    ],
    "auxiliaryFields": [],
    "backFields": []
  }
}
```

Comment: got any solution to fix the same? Because the same issue I'm also facing while I've written my code into C#

Answer (score -1):

Can you double check the format version of the pass. From your code, I can see it is mentioned as

`"formatVersion": 1,`

Can you try the format version 2 as given below,

```
"formatVersion": 2,
```

and see if that works?

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.